# Fixed Content Scrolling Layout

Tags: html, css, scroll, fixed

The site below uses a fixed background-image in each section, but how do I add fixed content (text, images) to each sections and keep the same scrolling effect?
http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ScrollingLayout/

Have a look at my example to get a better idea of what I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/w919y0gb/

My try:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.section {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    position: fixed;
}

#s1 {
    background-color: #f00;
}
#s2 {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
#s3 {
    background-color: #00f;
}
#s1 .content {
}
#s2 .content {
    margin-top: -400px;
}
#s3 .content {
    margin-top: -800px;
}

<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="section" id="s1">
        <div class="content">hello1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="s2">
        <div class="content">hello2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="s3">
        <div class="content">hello3</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

What I want:

The first section (red) should only display "hello1"

The second (green) only "hello2"

The third (blue) only "hello3"

Answer (score 0):

That reference site is simply using a `background-image` set to `fixed` like so:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w919y0gb/2/)

**UPDATE**

Ok I understand. You would need to do something like this with jquery and `$(window).scroll()` function:

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w919y0gb/4/)

using `positon: fixed` just breaks the element out of the flow of the document and it can't be contained by a parent so you need to use `absolute` and position it based on the `scrollTop` to give the appearance that it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I think you didn't understand my querstion: I'm asking to display the text correctly:
only hello1 on the first image, only hello 2 on the second...

Comment: Nice, thank you! :D
If there won't be any other answers I'll accept yours as solution.

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe? little hacky, but does the trick if you have set section heights:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div3').hide();
    $('.div2').hide();
    $('.div1').show();
    $('#wrapper').scroll(function(){
        console.log($('#wrapper').scrollTop());
        if($('#wrapper').scrollTop() > 945){
            $('.div3').show();
            $('.div2').hide();
            $('.div1').hide();
        }
        else if ($('#wrapper').scrollTop() > 465) {
            $('.div3').hide();
            $('.div2').show();
            $('.div1').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.div3').hide();
            $('.div2').hide();
            $('.div1').show();
        }
    });
});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w919y0gb/3/

with this, you could also modify the placement of the "hello1/hello2/hello3" to be in the same position instead of in different places. or you could just have one div in which you modify/replace the text from hello1/hello2/hello3 depending on the scroll position.  hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but with your mehtod the whole content just pops up at a certain position instead of being always there and just being overlayed.

Example:
Imagine that I placed a image with <img> in the content, your example could only display the whole image at a certain position, and the effect of overlay wouldn't work.
I hope I could explain myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the height of your webpage, and then make divs appear as you scroll up or down.
Heres a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/1738/

```
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 0 && y < 400) {
            $('#s1').fadeIn();
            $('#s3').fadeOut();
            $('#s2').fadeOut();
        } else if (y > 400 && y < 800) {
            $('#s1').fadeOut();
            $('#s2').fadeIn();
            $('#s3').fadeOut();
        }else if (y > 800) {
            $('#s3').fadeIn();
            $('#s2').fadeOut();
        }

    });
```

After you scroll a certain amount of pixels, divs will begin to appear and replace each other.

You may alter the value of `y` by setting the height of your body in css, as shown in the fiddle. You can then set the pixels conditions in the jQuery to whatever you like.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but it has a cool effect.
Thanks for the tip! :)